# What is the APCONRGFEE on my Dollar Rent a Car receipt?

Tags: car-rentals, fees-and-charges

I rented a car from Dollar Rent a Car at an airport in California and got charged an APCONRGFEE of $12.23. What fee is that? How is it different than the FACUSEFEE ($10)?

Comment: You might be best off asking Dollar themselves, the ways of chain rental car companies are often strange and bizare...

Comment: Airport Concession Recovery (Regain) Fee.  They are recouping the cost of operating a concession at the airport.  In *theory* it's a pass-through to the airport.  YMMV

Comment: FACUS = facility usage

Answer (score 3):

APCONRGFEE stands for [AirPort Concession Recovery Fee](http://simplepleasurestravel.com/what-are-those-car-rental-fees/) basically it's a charge you pay for the car rental company to be doing business at the airport.

- **Concession Recovery Fee** – At certain airport locations where a Rental Car company is an on-airport concessionaire, they are required to collect other mandatory charges from its customers and to remit them to the airport. These are sometimes referred to as Customer Facility Charge (CFC) , Airport Facility Charge (AFC), Transportation Facility Charge (TFC), or Airport Access Fee (AAF) or Concession Recoupment Fee (CRF).

I can't find the exact definition of the [FACUSEFEE](http://simplepleasurestravel.com/what-are-those-car-rental-fees/) is:

- **CFC** – This is a customer facility fee that is imposed by the airport in addition to  the Concession Recovery Fee.

Basically charges by the airport as well, just for use of the airport facilities.

Namely both are just different ways by the airport management of taking your money.

Comment: FACUSEFEE = Facility Use Fee.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid if you follow the link you will see that CFC amd FACUSE are the same thing.